# アロー関数の意味

Tags: javascript

次のようなアロー関数の書き方を見かけるのですが、意味がわかりません。
このアロー関数の意味を教えていただけませんか？

```
.then(server =>{
    console.log("server", server);

    return Promise.all([
        server.getPrimaryService(this.BUTTON_SERVICE_UUID)
    ]);
})
```

Comment: コード中のアロー関数は特別変わった書き方・使われ方をしているとは思いませんが、質問内容はアロー関数の一般的な意味でしょうか？それともPromiseの扱い方でしょうか？（はたまたそれ以外？）

Answer (score 3):

アロー関数の引数部分は、引数が1つの場合カッコを付けなくてもよいので、

```
.then((server) => {
   // 
})
```

と同じです。

Comment: わかりました！　そういうルールがあるのですね。